# Searching index in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, indexing, apache-spark-sql, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

search index data based on data in pyspark?

i already have index column in my dataset

i try this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

index_movies = movies.filter(movies["title"] == close_match) \
          .select(monotonically_increasing_id().alias("index_movies")) \
          .first()["index_movies"]
print(index_movies)
```

but, the result is 0. The *close_match* is the title of movie

Comment: first create the index and then filter -- but remember that it'll give different results for different runs. is `index_movies` the index column you're talking about?

Comment: yes, can you show how the code?